# How to resolve error "Error: 5069 ALTER DATABASE statement failed" when upgrading TFS data tier to TFS 2012?

Tags: tfs

We are trying to upgrade our TFS server from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012, but the data tier upgrade fails with the following error:

*TF400744: An error occurred while executing the following script: SetRecoveryModelToSimple.sql. Failed batch starts on the line 1. Statement line: 1. Script line: 1. Error: 5069 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.. For more information, see the configuration log.*

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Our SQL server was mirrored which apparently is what was causing the error.  Once we broke the mirroring then the upgrade worked.